# Using ARIMA with exogenous regressors for outlier detection in R

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, arima

I would like to detect outliers in real-time data that is aggregated per hour. For this example, I've selected the hourly pedestrian data from Melbourne, Australia
([Pedestrian volume (updated monthly)](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Transport-Movement/Pedestrian-volume-updated-monthly-/b2ak-trbp), [Pedestrian Counting System](http://www.pedestrian.melbourne.vic.gov.au/))

[I understand there are a large number of existing detection algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104882/detecting-outliers-in-time-series-ls-ao-tc-using-tsoutliers-package-in-r-how), which in time I'll learn and use.
In the short term I'd like to use the simplest approach. One such method is outlined by @Aksakal in the following stackexchange post:

[What algorithm should I use to detect anomalies on time-series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152644/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-detect-anomalies-on-time-series)

> I think the key is "unexpected" qualifier in your graph. In order to
>   detect the *unexpected* you need to have an idea of what's *expected*.
>
> I would start with a simple time series model such as AR(p) or
>   ARMA(p,q). Fit it to data, add seasonality as appropriate. For
>   instance, your SAR(1)(24) model could be: $y_{t}=c+\phi
>   y_{t-1}+\Phi_{24}y_{t-24}+\Phi_{25}y_{t-25}+\varepsilon_t$, where $t$
>   is time in hours. So, you'd be predicting the graph for the next hour.
>   Whenever the prediction error $e_t=y_t-\hat y_t$ is "too big" you
>   throw an alert.
>
> When you estimate the model you'll get the variance
>   $\sigma_\varepsilon$ of the error $\varepsilon_t$. Depending on your
>   distributional assumptions, such as normal, you can set the threshold
>   based on the probability, such as $|e_t|<3\sigma_\varepsilon$ for
>   99.7% or one-sided $e_t>3\sigma_\varepsilon$.
>
> The number of visitors is probably quite persistent, but super
>   seasonal. It might work better to try seasonal dummies instead of the
>   multiplicative seasonality, then you'd try ARMAX where X stands for
>   exogenous variables, which could be anything like holiday dummy, hour
>   dummies, weekend dummies etc.

Unfortunately the post does not go into details, hence I have a few questions:

Q.1) How do I calculate/extract the variance $\sigma_\varepsilon$ of the ARIMA error term $\epsilon$ from the fitted model produced by auto.arima(data, xreg = xreg)?
Below is a complete R example that uses multiple seasonality to capture daily, weekly and yearly seasonality. This is *not* optimised and is only presented as an example implementation to help answer question 2.

I wish to predict the thresholds for a whole year (or at least for a 30 day period), this means that h = 24hrs * 30 = 720.
In essence, I want to forecast, not the mean of the hourly pedestrian counts, but the upper expected number of pedestrians per hour (e.g. 3σ_ε) for h>>1 (eg, h = 720 hours (30 days) or even h = 24*365 = 8760 hours (1 year) ).

Q.2) How can I achieve this using the method above?

Example code to help solve the above questions.

```
library(rwalkr)
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

pedestrian <- as_tibble(rwalkr::run_melb( year = c(2015:2018) )) 

pedestrian_statelibrary <- pedestrian %>% 
  filter(Sensor == "State Library") %>% 
  left_join(tsibble::holiday_aus(2015:2018, state='VIC'), by=c( 'Date' = 'date' )) %>%
  mutate(holiday = replace_na(holiday, ''),
         Count = ifelse(Count == 0, NA, Count))

# Replace all counts of zero with NA so Box-Cox transform lambda = 0 and constrain output to +ve.
pedestrian_statelibrary_train <- pedestrian_statelibrary %>% filter(Date >= as.Date('2015-05-13'), Date < as.Date('2017-01-01') )
pedestrian_statelibrary_test <- pedestrian_statelibrary %>% filter(Date >= as.Date('2017-01-01') )

# tsbox functions to convert tsibble to tz indirectly. Must be a better way of doing this...
pedestrian_statelibrary_train_zoo <- tsbox::ts_zoo( pedestrian_statelibrary_train %>% select(Date_Time, Count) )
pedestrian_statelibrary_train_ts <-    tsbox::ts_ts(pedestrian_statelibrary_train_zoo)

pedestrian_statelibrary_test_zoo <- tsbox::ts_zoo(    pedestrian_statelibrary_test %>% select(Date_Time, Count) )
pedestrian_statelibrary_test_ts <- tsbox::ts_ts(pedestrian_statelibrary_test_zoo)


## Create external regressors.
xreg_holidays_train <- model.matrix(~as.factor(pedestrian_statelibrary_train$holiday))
xreg_holidays_train <- xreg_holidays_train[,-1]  # remove intercept.
# Remove 1st level from levels()
colnames(xreg_holidays_train) <- levels(as.factor(pedestrian_statelibrary_train$holiday))[-1]

xreg_holidays_test <- model.matrix(~as.factor(pedestrian_statelibrary_test$holiday))
xreg_holidays_test <- xreg_holidays_test[,-1]  # remove intercept.
colnames(xreg_holidays_test) <- levels(as.factor(pedestrian_statelibrary_test$holiday))[-1]

# periods (intervals(samples) per period) for hourly data.
period_day <- 24
period_week <- 24*7
period_year <- 24*365.25

seasonal_periods = c(period_day, period_week, period_year)

pedestrian_statelibrary_train_msts <- msts(pedestrian_statelibrary_train_ts,
                                     start = start(pedestrian_statelibrary_train_ts), 
                                             seasonal.periods = seasonal_periods) 

pedestrian_statelibrary_test_msts <- msts(pedestrian_statelibrary_test_ts, 
                                      start = start(pedestrian_statelibrary_test_ts), 
                                       seasonal.periods = seasonal_periods) 

# set number of Fourier terms per season. Not optimal.
Ks = c(12, 10, 2)

xreg_train <- cbind( seasonality = fourier(pedestrian_statelibrary_train_msts, K = Ks), 
                 holidays = xreg_holidays_train ) 

######################################
## Fit model of exogenous factors and ARIMA as error
######################################
fit <- pedestrian_statelibrary_train_msts %>% 
  auto.arima( xreg = xreg_train,
              seasonal=FALSE,
              stepwise = FALSE,
              parallel = TRUE,
              num.cores = NULL,
              lambda = 0
              ) 

######################################
## Forecast
######################################

fc <- forecast( fit, 
            xreg=cbind( seasonality = fourier(pedestrian_statelibrary_test_msts, K = Ks), 
                        holidays = xreg_holidays_test) 
) 

######################################
## Check residuals and accuracy.
######################################

checkresiduals(fit)

checkresiduals(fc)

accuracy(fc, pedestrian_statelibrary_test_msts)


######################################
## Display fitted model and forecast using interactive dygraph.
######################################

# Plotting `forecast` prediction using `dygraphs`
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624634/plotting-forecast-prediction-using-dygraphs#43668603
as.forecast.ts <- function(forecast_obj){

  training <- forecast_obj$x
  lower <- forecast_obj$lower[,2]
  upper <- forecast_obj$upper[,2]
  point_forecast <- forecast_obj$mean

  cbind(training, lower, upper, point_forecast)
}

fc_ts <- as.forecast.ts(fc)

# Add the time stamps back to ts object.
idx_train <- pedestrian_statelibrary_train %>% ungroup() %>%    select(Date_Time) %>% as.data.frame()
idx_test <- pedestrian_statelibrary_test %>% ungroup() %>% select(Date_Time) %>% as.data.frame()
idx_all <- rbind(idx_train, idx_test)

# Append testing values to fc_ts object, by left joining two xts objects.
test_xts <- as.xts(x = pedestrian_statelibrary_test %>% 
                     dplyr::ungroup() %>%
                     as.data.frame() %>% 
                     dplyr::select( Count ) %>%
                     dplyr::rename( 'testing' = 'Count'), 
                   pedestrian_statelibrary_test$Date_Time)


fc_xts <- as.xts(x = fc_ts %>% 
                   as.data.frame(),
                 idx_all$Date_Time )

fc_xts <- fc_xts %>% xts::merge.xts(test_xts, join='left')

dygraph(data = fc_xts, main = "Pedestrian traffic Forecasting for State Library.") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector %>%
  dySeries(name = "training", label = "Train") %>%
  dySeries(name = 'testing', label = "Test") %>%
  dySeries(name = "point_forecast", label = "Predicted") %>%
  dyLegend(show = "always", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
  dyOptions(axisLineColor = "navy", gridLineColor = "grey")
```

Comment: Hi @SamuelLiew, I edited the question to be more focused as requested. I believe this is clearer and focused. May you re-open the question? Cheers

Comment: Agree with @SamuelLiew. This is question is too broad with large amount of code. It is unclear what is the specific problem (any error?, undesired result?), requiring specific solution.

Comment: Fair call @SamuelLiew. I'll hopefully get help with the question on stats.SE and update this question as appropriate.